# Regex for picking word with atleast two underscores

Tags: regex

I am trying to parse a text document which contains some words with underscores.

I was looking to regex match but am failing currently.

I was looking at fetching (line by line) words which have atleast two underscores or words with atleast two underscores and forward slash + atleast three digits.

I have gotten till

```
([a-zA-Z]+(?:_{2,}[a-zA-Z]+)*)
```

The correct match examples are

```
VOK17_05_530_526002 *(has atleast than two underscores)*
VIE_ROMS_002 *(has atleast than two underscores)*
VOK_OVSZ_001/002 *(has atleast  two underscores and a forward slash + three digits)*
```

Input sample

```
VOK17_05_530_526002 502 504 BACU VIE_ROMS_002 VIE_ROMS_001 VOK_OVSZ_001/002
VOK17_05_530_526002 401 401 LGCU VIE_ROMS_002 VIE_ROMS_001 VOK_OVSZ_001/002
VOK17_05_530_526002 510 513 BACU VIE_ROMS_002 VIE_ROMS_001 VOK_OVSZ_001/002
VOK17_05_530_526002 515 515 BACU VIE_ROMS_002 VIE_ROMS_001 VOK_OVSZ_001/002
VOK17_05_530_526003 503 506 BACU VIE_ROMS_002 VIE_ROMS_001 VOK_OVSZ_001/002
```

I am trying out my regex @ https://regex101.com/r/yToVtc/1

If someone can help out here, I would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
\b[A-Za-z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+(?:_[0-9]{3,})+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*(?:/[0-9]+)?\b
```

In parts

- `\b` Word boundary
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed
- `(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+` Repeat 1+ times an underscore and 1+ times any of the listed
- `(?:_[0-9]{3,})+` Match at least the second underscore and 3 or more digits
- `(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*` Repeat 0+ times and underscore and any of the listed
- `(?:/[0-9]+)?` Match an optional `/` and 1+ digits
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nWRx3n/1)

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_[a-zA-Z0-9]+){2,}(?:/\d{3})?\b
```

**Explanation:**

```
\b                  # word boundary
[a-zA-Z0-9]+        # 1 or more alphanum
(?:                 # non capture group
  _                 # underscore
  [a-zA-Z0-9]+      # 1 or more alphanum
){2,}               # end group, must appear 2 or more times
(?:                 # non capture group
  /                 # a slask
  \d{3}             # 3 digits
)?                  # end group, optional
\b                  # word boundary
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/v2Tjh5/1)

Answer (score 0):

Regex for a text string with at least two underscores

```
^[^_]*_[^_]*_.*$
```

- `^` - Start of match
- `[^_]*` Then zero to any number of characters which are not an underscore
- `_` Then an underscore
- `[^_]*` Then zero to any number of characters which are not an underscore
- `_` Then an underscore
- `.*` Then zero to any number of characters
- `$` - End of match

Answer (score 0):

`([^\s]*_[^\s]*){2,}` will match any word (any string without a space) that contains at least two underscores by finding two consequetive groups of any number of non spaces, an underscore and again howevermany "word"-symbols are to come.

You can replace `[^\s]*` with any definition of "word" you like.

You can also add `?:` after the first bracket to avoid capturing the groups.

Answer (score 0):

The regex below uses a *lookahead assertion* to  simplify matters:

```
\b(?=(?:([A-Za-z0-9]*_){2}))[A-Za-z0-9_]+(?:\/\d{3,})?\b
```

1. `\b(?=(?:([A-Za-z0-9]*_){2}))` Matches a word boundary if and only if is followed by `([A-Za-z0-9]*_){2}`, which is to say, a string that contains 0 or more of the legal alphanumeric characters followed by a '_', all repeated twice. This is the lookahead assertion that ensures our match in step 2 below contains at least two underscore characters.
2. `[A-Za-z0-9_]+` Matches the legal characters one or more times.
3. `(?:\/\d{3,})?` An optional forward slash followed by 3 or more digits.
4. `\b` Matches a word boundary.

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/KSWs8a/2/)